# java.lang.ClassCastException when trying to import document entities in a TestNG xml file with TestNG version 7.3.0

Tags: java, testng

I'm getting an error when trying to import parameters from another xml file using document entities. TestNG 6.9.11 works as expected, 7.3.0 and 7.4.0-SNAPSHOT crash with the following stacktrace:

```
org.testng.TestNGException: java.lang.ClassCastException: class sun.net.www.protocol.file.FileURLConnection cannot be cast to class java.net.HttpURLConnection (sun.net.www.protocol.file.FileURLConnection and java.net.HttpURLConnection are in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap')
    at org.testng.TestNG.parseSuite(TestNG.java:354)
    at org.testng.TestNG.initializeSuitesAndJarFile(TestNG.java:374)
    at org.testng.TestNG.initializeEverything(TestNG.java:1017)
    [..]
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: class sun.net.www.protocol.file.FileURLConnection cannot be cast to class java.net.HttpURLConnection (sun.net.www.protocol.file.FileURLConnection and java.net.HttpURLConnection are in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap')
    at org.testng.xml.TestNGContentHandler.lambda$new$0(TestNGContentHandler.java:62)
    at org.testng.xml.TestNGContentHandler.resolveEntity(TestNGContentHandler.java:117)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.EntityResolverWrapper.resolveEntity(EntityResolverWrapper.java:111)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLEntityManager.resolveEntityAsPerStax(XMLEntityManager.java:1025)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLEntityManager.startEntity(XMLEntityManager.java:1306)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanEntityReference(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:1858)
    [..]
```

Main TestNG xml file:

```
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "https://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd" [
    <!ENTITY parent SYSTEM "xml/test/parameters.xml">
]>
      
<suite name="VerifyTests" parallel="tests" thread-count="10" preserve-order="true">
    
    &parent;
        
    <test name="TestName1">     
        <classes>
            <class name="tests.testcode.VerifyTests" />             
        </classes>
    </test>
</suite>
```

Secondary xml file:

```
<parameter name="browser" value="chrome" />
```

The class contains a single @Test method with a log message, I have the same error in Eclipse as well as running TestNg from shell. I would say that it's a TestNG bug caused by the line

```
 HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
```

in m_redirectionAwareResolver from TestNGContentHandler, but I find it hard to believe that nobody else had this problem before, my searches got nothing so maybe it's something at my end. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Will be fixed in TestNG 7.5.0 : https://github.com/cbeust/testng/issues/2501